# ERROR: Bucket name must match the regex "^[a-zA-Z0-9.\-_]{1,255}$"

Tags: python, regex, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, bucket

When I try to upload images to a bucket, it throw an error `"Invalid bucket name "thum.images ": Bucket name must match the regex "^[a-zA-Z0-9.\-_]{1,255}$""`.

I think there is nothing wrong with a bucket name.

This is my code to upload image:

```
def upload_thumbnail_image(image_key, thumbnail_image):
    thumbnail_image_bucket = os.environ['thumbnail_bucket']
    thumbnail_image = #image path
    image_key = EFE3-27C8-EEB3-4987/3612d0bc-bdfd-49de-82ee-3e66cbb06807.jpg
    try:
        new_object = client.upload_file(thumbnail_image, thumbnail_image_bucket, image_key)
        return new_object
    except Exception as Exc:
        set_log(Exc.args[0],True)
```

Comment: The error seems to imply your bucket name contains a whitespace at the end of it.. which the regex does not allow.

Comment: Your regex actually does not allow a hyphen `-` because hyphen acts as a range specifier in your character class. If you want to literally include a hyphen then change your regex to this `^[a-zA-Z0-9.-_-]{1,255}$`

Comment: @PushpeshKumarRajwanshi the regex is part of the error message, coming from either the SDK or the service itself.  Markdown was suppessing a backslash.  Edited.

Comment: Your image_key should be quoted.

Comment: The regex does allow for a hyphen and is escaped as such.  [a-zA-Z0-9.\-_].  The issue is the trailing whitespace as @FatalError found.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot is correct.  It's coming back from Amazon's `boto3` library.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The `"Invalid bucket name "thum.images ": Bucket name must match the regex "^[a-zA-Z0-9.\-_]{1,255}$""` error means just what it says: the bucket name must contain some typo or is just wrong as it should meet the following pattern:

- `^` - start of string
- `[a-zA-Z0-9.\-_]{1,255}` - 1 to 255 ASCII letters, digits, dots, `-` or `_` chars
- `$` - end of string.

**You may [test your bucket names online here](https://regex101.com/r/2IFv8B/1)**.

There can be no whitespaces in the bucket name.

I often get this error because an extra slash gets into the bucket name after I copy/paste the bucket name from the S3 Web page, like `aws s3 sync s3:///my-bucket/folder folder`, where instead of the triple backslashes there must be just two.

Comment: Aren't the forward slashes invalid characters according to that regex?

Answer (score 3):

I received this error because I had an invisible non-printing character (the BOM, aka Byte Order Mark, aka U+FEFF) at the beginning of an csv file that contained the s3 path.  I was able to find it with this python code:

```
print(":".join("{:02x}".format(ord(c)) for c in s3_path))
```

which resulted in `feff:`... at the beginning of the string which tipped me off.  You would expect to see output like `6d:79:2d:70:61:74:68` (i.e. two digit hex numbers).

(Update 2022) As per the comment from Ben Allred, there are other non-printing characters that could also cause the same error and be difficult to detect.

Comment: Upvoted. UTF8 with BOM is working for me but this answer led me to finding that I had CRLF in my sh file with the bucket name which was causing the problem for me.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue and it had a mistake while I stored some path in a consts file

`PATH = 'gs://same_bucket/same_folder/some_file.csv'`

and in other script tried to read it with additional `gs://`

`df = spark.read.csv(f"gs://{PATH})`

Answer (score 0):

If you are running the code in Jupyter code then make sure you don't place your bucket names as str like "bucket_name" it should be just bucket_name=name

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to create sub-folders inside the bucket, you can prefix the locations in this File_key variable. For example, /subfolder/file_name.txt

Answer (score 0):

Check if have erased the <> characters already and just write the bucket name between the quotes ''

Answer (score 0):

I was doing same thing with `boto3` and noticed one thing.

Make sure to write the bucket name **without** "s3://" prefix. Obviously, including slashes will be violation of the regex as mentioned by @Overbyte.

E.g.

```py
thumbnail_image_bucket = "my-bucket" # Without 's3://'
```