# Parameter validation failed:\nInvalid bucket name \"\": Bucket name must match the regex [JMeter]

Tags: amazon-s3, jmeter, performance-testing, web-api-testing

When I try to make a post request using JMeter to S3 bucket AWS, I get the above-mentioned error message. My body of the request does not contain "backslash" and also my bucket name does not contain "backslash". Not sure why am getting this issue. Can someone please help me resolve this issue?

Http Request:
[image]

HTTP Header Manager
[image]

ViewResultTree Output:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is an AWS validation error for S3. Mind following this thread?

[ERROR: Bucket name must match the regex "^[a-zA-Z0-9.\-_]{1,255}$"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54049154/error-bucket-name-must-match-the-regex-a-za-z0-9-1-255)