# GCP Error: error: bucket name validation failed

Tags: google-cloud-platform, bucket

I was trying to create a bucket on gcp and I got this error:
`Error: error: bucket name validation failed bkt-dlkh-sx-cicd-proj-gcp-projects-build-artifacts--prj-dlkh-sx-b-cicd-o7qz`

The message is not very explicit on why is failing, I though it was a regex problem based on https://stackoverflow.com/a/62349388/13686796 but not really.

Answer (score 3):

It turned out it was too long. The limit on GCP is 63 characters

Answer (score 0):

Yes, @valcapp is correct. The bucket name you have given seems to be 76 characters.
Please check the docs for more information about the limits
https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/buckets#naming